Basis of the image

Find the basis of the image of a matrix: $$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & -2 \\
2 & -1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I'm somewhat confused about the concept of the basis of the image, and I find it perplexing. I find the row-reduced echelon form of the matrix: $$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and then take the columns $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0  \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1  \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$, $v_3=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1  \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$. Is this a basis? Or can I only take vectors from the original matrix? $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1  \\
2 
\end{pmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1  \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix}$, $v_3=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-2  \\
4
\end{pmatrix}$.
I also used a different approach. I found the images of the standard basis vectors under the action of operator A and ended up with the same vectors: $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1  \\
2 
\end{pmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1  \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix}$, $v_3=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-2  \\
4
\end{pmatrix}$. Since they are linearly independent, they form a basis. Is the basis of the image unique? Or can there be different options?

(a) You say you found the reduced echelon form - if you meant row-reduced that's not right, column-reduced is what you need (b) your second approach is correct (c) it is indeed silly to ask for "the" basis, except in a couple of trivial cases there is always more than one basis for a vector space.

As the determinant is $1 \ne 0$ take the 3 columns of the matix as a basis. For example applying your matrix to vector $\pmatrix{1\0\0}$ gives the first column...

@ancientmathematician Since this is a three-dimensional space, will the standard basis be a basis for the image, for example?

@GlebCloudy Yes, actually. In particular, the linear map defined by the matrix is bijective so the image is all of $\mathbb R^3$.

You have to find the basis of the image of the following matrix.
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & -2 \\
2 & -1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, the image of this matrix that is defined by $Im(A) = \{Ax: x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\} = \{x_{1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\-1  \\2 \end{pmatrix} + x_{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\1  \\-1 \end{pmatrix} + x_{3}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\-2  \\4 \end{pmatrix}\}$.
Since $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\-1  \\2 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 \\1  \\-1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 \\-2  \\4 \end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent vector of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$, and also in $Im(A)$. So this is a basic image of $A$. Now any reduced form of these vectors, which is the same if you reduced the matrix $A$, and then their $3$ columns can perform a basis of $Im(A)$.

Here, the first isomorhy theorem is helpful. Because, for a linear function $f: X \rightarrow Y$, we have:
$$
X/\ker(f) \cong im(f) \subseteq Y,
$$
you can calculate the dimension of your image. In your case, you have $\dim(X)=3$, can you compute $\dim(\ker(f))$?. When you have that, you can easilly see what the dimension of then image is.
Once you have the dimension of that space, it is sufficient to find that many linearly independent vectors in that space. Of course, your solution is not unique, but it is no problem! Imagine the identity function, you can describe your base space in (infinitely)-many ways, so the endspace will have that property too.

If you do column operations, the span of the columns doesn't change and when the  columns become obviously linearly independent, you are done.
